# Prepending Windows include paths in makefile with variable include argument

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I have a project that I want to compile on a Windows system with both Microsoft Visual Studio and GCC.  I have an environment variable for selecting which compiler to use (e.g. COMPILER=VS or COMPILER=GCC).  The first problem is that the "include option" for GCC is -I while the include option for Visual Studio is /I.

I therefore have a variable that specifies the required include option flag:

```
ifeq ($(COMPILER), VS)
  INCLUDE_DELIMITER = /I
else
  INCLUDE_DELIMITER = -I
endif
```

Now I build up a list of paths that need to be included:

```
COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH   = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include"
UCRT_INCLUDE_PATH       = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt"
UM_INCLUDE_PATH         = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um"
WINFAMILY_INCLUDE_PATH  = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared"

INCLUDE_LIST = $(COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH) $(UCRT_INCLUDE_PATH) $(UM_INCLUDE_PATH) $(WINFAMILY_INCLUDE_PATH)
```

So now INCLUDE_LIST is a list of quoted strings (due to the spaces in the windows paths).  How can I create a variable that prepends the INCLUDE_DELIMITER (compiler specific) to each of these strings?

I've tried:

```
INCLUDES = $(patsubst, "%", $(INCLUDE_DELIMITER)"%", $(INCLUDE_LIST))
```

to no avial.  I also tried:

```
    INCLUDES = $(foreach d, $(INCLUDE_LIST), $(INCLUDE_DELIMITER)$d)
```

but that resulted in each space in INCLUDE_LIST being detected as a new word.

Comment: Have you considered using cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't know if it's a typo in your question but the syntax is `$(patsubst <pat>,<pat>,<words>)`; there's no comma after the `patsubst` keyword.

Second, in general GNU make is not capable of dealing with whitespace in its functions.  The `%` in `patsubst` refers to each whitespace separated *word*, so the words in the expansion of `$(INCLUDE_LIST)` will be: first `"C:\Program`, next `Files`, next `(x86)\Microsoft`, etc.  None of those will match the pattern `"%"`.

You could try this instead:

```
$(patsubst "C:\Program,$(INCLUDE_DELIMITER)"C:\Program,$(INCLUDE_LIST))
```

Third, you really don't want to use backslashes in arguments to GNU make.  Luckily most Windows tools including Visual Studio will accept forward slashes in pathname delimiters as well as backslashes.  I recommend you switch to using those.

Comment: Yes, you correctly identified my typos.  This solution works as suggested.  I was hoping there existed something a bit more elegant (such as regex support), but for now I have to go with what works.